# Javadoc creation in eclipse fails to create index files, stylesheets and so on

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

When I generate javadoc in eclipse it fails to create needed files such as index, allclasses, stylesheets resources etc. The only outcome of the generation are the raw html java documentation of each package.

Ex, you would expect following outcome in your javadoc target folder:

```
javadoc-target-dir
                |_com
                |   |
                |   foo..
                |
                |_index-files
                |         |...
                |
                |_resources
                |        |...
                |
                |_allclasses-frame
                |_allclasses_noframe
                |_help-doc
                |_index
                |_overview-tree
                |_package-list
                |_stylesheet
```

but I end up with only this:

```
javadoc-target-dir
                |_com
                |   |
                *   foo...
```

no index files or other resources are generated.

I generate the javadoc as usual in eclipse using `jdk1.8.0_05`, I really don't have a clue what's causing this behavior. One thing I've noticed in the  console when the javadoc is generated is that it never comes to `Building index for all classes...` maybe it could be a hint of what's happening?